# How to add Google Map in using latest API in an existing older android project?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an old Android project where I used Location API and Google map. I found many API updated. If I generate a new project from Android Studio for Map activity, it generates files and instructs how to get Google API key and how to add that key inside google_maps_api.xml(debug) file. This is generated at app/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml. This files value is read in The  AndroidManifest.xml as

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

I want to do the same for an existing old Android project. I generate google API key  and add it in the  AndroidManifest.xml as

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxx" />
```

xxxxxxxxxx = the actual API key from google console.

but it doesn't work. I can see a blank map. Also in the logcat it shows:-

> E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for
>   how to correctly set up

so how to add it correctly in an existing old Android project?

Comment: you have given the permission ?

Comment: I have these:-    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.home.ma.photolocationnote.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Comment: can you post your java code ?

Comment: it is huge. I can share github link where I am hosting this project. let me commit latest updatee and then I share the link.

Comment: ok give it.....

Comment: here it is: https://github.com/madsum/PhotoLocationNote . It is huge. The only issue is the MapsActivity where it shows blank map.

Comment: did you enable map api in google console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180665/discussion-between-masiboo-and-faiz-mir).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Problem is in your Api key Please Check your api key..**

I tested your Map by putting my Api key and its work ..

Please Generate new Api key And try it.

**Follow these steps to get an API key:**

```html
Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console.
1.Create or select a project.
2.Click Continue to enable the API and any related services.
3.On the Credentials page, get an API key. 
Note: If you have an existing unrestricted API key, or a key with browser restrictions, you may use that key.
```

**Here is My Screen Shot of the map**

[image: Here is the Working Map]

Comment: yes, it works when I created a new project in google console. I was using the same key for another project. So API keys can't be shared between 2 projects.

Comment: @masiboo Hope my answer help you

Answer (score 0):

try to obtain a new [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup). possibly the current key had been invalidated

... due to either package-name change or signing-key fingerprint change.